# Is there synaptic in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

I am now using 12.10 version of ubuntu and i am about to install 13.04.I have a question.Is there synaptic package manager in ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 1):

Yes synaptic is available in every version of Ubuntu and indeed you can install it in `13.04`. Since it is not installed by default you have to install it from repository. You can install it from either way:

1. Install it using `Ubuntu Software Center`:

   - open `Ubuntu Software Center` and search for `Synaptic`
   - click on <kbd>Install</kbd> button.
2. Install it using terminal:

   - open terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):
   - execute following commands:

     ```
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install synaptic
     ```

That's it..

Answer (score 0):

To install Synaptic Package Manager, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```